# Javascript: making the global eval() behave like object.eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

Ok- I have a very specific case for which I need to use eval(). Before people tell me that I shouldn't be using eval() at all, let me disclose that I'm aware of eval's performance issues, security issues and all that jazz. I'm using it in a very narrow case. The problem is this:

I seek a function which will write a variable to whatever scope is passed into it, allowing for code like this:

```
function mysteriousFunction(ctx) {
//do something mysterious in here to write
//"var myString = 'Oh, I'm afraid the deflector shield will be 
//quite operational when your friends arrive.';"
}

mysteriousFunction(this);
alert(myString);
```

I've tried using global eval() to do this, faking the execution context with closures, the 'with' keyword etc. etc. I can't make it work. The only thing I've found that works is:

```
function mysteriousFunction(ctx) {
ctx.eval("var myString = 'Our cruisers cant repel firepower of that magnitude!';");
}

mysteriousFunction(this);
alert(myString); //alerts 'Our cruisers cant repel firepower of that magnitude!'
```

However, the above solution requires the object.eval() function, which is deprecated. It works but it makes me nervous. Anyone care to take a crack at this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I just want to say that I like your taste in sample code.

Comment: @Alex: Do you have an issue referring to it as `this.myString`? See the comments in my answer for detailed discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You can say something like this:

```
function mysteriousFunction(ctx) {
   ctx.myString = "[value here]";
}

mysteriousFunction(this);
alert(myString);     // catch here: if you're using it in a anonymous function, you need to refer to as this.myString (see comments)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/HfFKJ/

You can also refactor it like this:

```
function mysteriousFunction() {
   this.myString = "[value here]";   // we'll change the meaning of this when we call the function
}
```

And then `call` (pun intended) your function with different contexts like this:

```
var ctx = {};
mysteriousFunction.call(ctx);
alert(ctx.myString);

mysteriousFunction.call(this);
alert(myString);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/HfFKJ/4/

Comment: @Matthew: If you're declaring an anonymous function, then you've to call `alert(this.myString)`. Its a good catch though, I updated it in my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/cgKnF/1/

Comment: Right, but I think the point is that he doesn't want to write `this.myString`.

Comment: @Matthew: In his OP, he doesn't have it in a anonymous function either. If you're changing the scope, then `this.myString` causes no harm. Its much better than using eval anyway.

Comment: I interpreted "whatever scope" to possibly include anonymous functions (among other things).

Comment: @Alex: I don't think I provided a solution. :)  Do you mean Mrchief's?  Please post the details of what you got working.

Comment: @Matthew: rock on- your solution is what I'm looking for. I played with it a little and eventually got this thing to work:


    function mysteriousFunction(nameOfVar) {
    this[nameOfVar] = "Life finds a way..."; 
    }
    
    function ianMalcom() {
 
    mysteriousFunction.call(this, 'myString');
    alert(myString);
    
    }
    
    ianMalcom();

Very happy to not have to use eval() at all- it never occurred to me that I could ditch the variable declaration altogether. Thanks everyone who answered!

Comment: @Alex, you're never creating an object there, so `this` is `window` and `myString` is global.

Comment: @Alex: I think you're confusing me and Matthew!

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6EHh/)

EDIT: As @Mathew so kindly pointed out my code MAKES NO SENSE! So a working example using strings:

```
function mysteriousFunction(ctx) {
    eval(ctx + ".myString = 'Our cruisers cant repel firepower of that magnitude!';");
}
var obj = {};
mysteriousFunction("obj");
alert(obj.myString);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If you're just assigning to window (not the narrowest scope), why even use `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure it's impossible to write to the function scope (i.e. simulate `var`) from another function, without `eval`.

Note that when you pass `this`, you're either passing the window, or an object.  Neither identifies a function (the scope of a non-global `var`).